# Babel plugins - Member access with index

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am writing a babel plugin. I came across a place where I need to use index operator. This is code I want to get `a[Symbol.something](b)`, however, I can't seem to find a way to do it. I have tried doing something like this:

```js
types.callExpression(
    types.memberExpression(types.Identifier('a'), 
        types.memberExpression(types.Identifier('Symbol'), types.Identifier('something'))
    ),
    [types.Identifier('b')]
)
```

However, it throws error `TypeError: Property property of MemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier","PrivateName"] but instead g
ot "MemberExpression"`. I googled my problem, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `computed` parameter of [`MemberExpression`](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#building-nodes).

For example,

```js
types.MemberExpression( types.Identifier('foo'), types.Identifier('bar') );
```

will generate `foo.bar`, whereas

```js
types.MemberExpression( types.Identifier('foo'), types.Identifier('bar'), true );
```

will generate `foo[bar]`.

Thus, your code should be:

```js
types.CallExpression(
  types.MemberExpression(
    types.Identifier('a'),
    types.MemberExpression(types.Identifier('Symbol'), types.Identifier('something')),
    true
  ),
  [types.Identifier('b')]
);
```

This will generate `a[Symbol.something](b)`.